# how to make Carbon null in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I'm making a table in Laravel and I want my "besttime" to be a `nullable` but it's returning the current time if I keep it empty.
(I'm using carbon because I want the `H:i` format without the seconds)
here's what my input looks like

```
@foreach ($records as $record)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($record->besttime)->format('H:i') }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: {{empty($record->besttime)?null: Carbon\Carbon::parse($record->besttime)->format('H:i')}}

Comment: You can also (apparently) use `Carbon::make($record->besttime)` which will return a carbon instance or null if you pass it null. Check the relevant case as well https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/issues/1917

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will  suggest you to add mutators in model so you can keep code simpler in blade file

```
public function getBesttimeAttribute($value)
{
    return empty($value)
        ? null
        : Carbon::parse($value)->format('H:i');
}
```

so in your view you can do

```
<td>{{ $record->besttime }}</td>
```

suppose if you dont want to modify orginal values then you can create custom attribute and append it to request

```
public function getCustomBestTimeAttribute()
{
    return empty($this->besttime)
        ? null
        : Carbon::parse($this->besttime)->format('H:i');
}
```

and set

```
public $appends = ["custom_best_time"];
```

so in your view you can do

```
<td>{{ $record->custom_best_time}}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to make Carbon null.

```
 Carbon::make($record)->format('H:i')
```

Comment: If `Carbon::make($record)` returns null it will try to call the method `format()` on a null object. You can use `Carbon::make($record)?->format('H:i');` to prevent the exception